# Assigning variables into a API text string postgis

Tags: postgis, api

I am trying to assign values to variable in PostGIS.

I have a API similar to: [example](http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=17/x/y)

I want to create a trigger that parse the x,y coordinates from my geometry column to a field containing the link to the map in my table

```
create table foo
(
id serial,
link text,
geom geometry(point)
);
```

This query give me the x, y in text.

```
SELECT ROUND(ST_X(geom)::NUMERIC,0)::TEXT, ROUND(ST_Y(geom)::numeric,0)::TEXT FROM foo
```

Asign the X,Y somehow to the link column:

```
UPDATE foo
set link=http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=17/$x/$y
```

I want the update to result in something like http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=13/-27.1274/-109.3370

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to do something like:

```
UPDATE foo
set link= 'http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=17/' || ROUND(ST_X(geom)::NUMERIC,0)::TEXT || '/' || ROUND(ST_Y(geom)::numeric,0)::TEXT
```

Comment: Yes that was just what I was looking for! Thank you very much! Good to know that I can mix the string and query like that together!

Answer (score 2):

Putting it all together for those who are interested

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo.map_api()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$BEGIN
NEW.link:= 'http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=17/' || ROUND(ST_X(new.geom)::NUMERIC,0)::TEXT || '/' || ROUND(ST_Y(new.geom)::numeric,0)::TEXT;
RETURN NEW;
    END;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION foo.map_api()
  OWNER TO postgres;


CREATE TRIGGER update_map_link
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON foo
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE foo.map_api();
```